# Merging Polygon Shapefiles in Python

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

My python3 script created the variable `geometries_list` whose value is a list of shapefiles, each  a polygon representing a geographic area

```
[<shapefile.Shape at 0x7f060abfae48>,
 <shapefile.Shape at 0x7f05dcaf1cc0>,
 <shapefile.Shape at 0x7f060a86b278>,
 <shapefile.Shape at 0x7f05da470668>]
```

I want to "merge" the polygons. I tried the following code

```
from functools import reduce
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
union = reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), geometries_list)
```

but it gives the result:
**AttributeError: 'Shape' object has no attribute 'union'**

I see another method which involves creating a shapefilewriter object and successively overwriting each polygon on the list https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103033/using-pyshp-to-merge-two-shapefiles  This approach might work, but each overwrite is saved to disk

Comment: the following resolved the issue

    geometries_list = [geometry.Polygon(x.points) for x in geometries_list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps worth mentioning that [`shapely.ops.unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) is a more effective method for merging shapes.

You can convert the `shapefile.Shape` objects to `shapely.Polygon` objects through their GeoJSON representation and merge them as follows.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.geometry.ops import unary_union

union = unary_union([shape(s.__geo_interface__) for s in geometries_list])
```